# Is there verbose logging for Bazel?

Tags: java, bazel

I dig around Bazel source code, there aren't much logging it seems. Is there a way to enable some kind of verbose mode so I can see what bazel is doing?

Also there seems to be various kind of debug options but I cant seem to comprehend yet, if I want to debug say java_library how should I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To debug what Bazel does and why:

- To list the commands Bazel executes, use the ["--[no]subcommands" flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html).
- To request listing just the failing commands, use the ["--[no]verbose_failures" flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html).
- To request writing an explanation of the build, use the ["--explain" flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html). Use "--[no]verbose_explanations" to adjust verbosity.

To debug programs you built with Bazel:

- You cannot debug java_library rules
- You can debug java_binary rules. Build with "-c dbg" (see the ["--compilation_mode" flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html)), then run the binary with `bazel-bin/path/to/java/program --debug=<port>`

EDIT: added info about `--verbose_failures` and `--verbose_explanations`

Comment: "To debug programs you built with Bazel" Nah I actually meant debugging Bazel build itself, like when it is running https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/java/BazelJavaLibraryRule.java

Comment: FYI, you don't need to add these flags to `.bazelrc`, all that does is letting you use the `--config=debug` flag in the future. You can instead just pass the flags directly to Bazel to build a debuggable Bazel binary: `bazel build //src:bazel -c dbg --javacopt="-g" --copt="-g" --strip="never"`

Comment: It will yield
bazel build //src:bazel -c dbg --javacopt="-g" --copt="-g" --strip="never"
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: bazel should not be called from a bazel output directory. The pertinent workspace directory is: '/Users/hoaphan/dev/AlexCal/bazel'
INFO: Invocation ID: f5fa1836-9182-445e-bb7d-8b7839bb9002
This works for me:
bazel --host_jvm_debug build //src/main/java/com/example/cmdline:runner_deploy.jar

Not sure if --jobs=1 will make it better.

Comment: Copy the file (`bazel-bin/src/bazel`) out of the output tree, e.g. to `$HOME/devbazel`, and run from there.

Comment: Alas, but all of those flags still do not show me what bazel is actually _putting_ onto the command line to build and (fail to) link my program. If I were to make a build system (I have), this would be close to the first feature I'd make.